# Highcharts Negative Values Column Graph Bottom Radius

Tags: highcharts

I am having column graph which contains positive and negative values column graph, I need to give the border radius top only for the positive and negative Graph. But if I'm trying to add the border radius top for the negative column graph it was not working. Kindly let me know how to give the only border radius top for negative column graph using highcharts in react js.

[refer image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yq4n.png)

For example ,in the image provided, for  I want border radius at -5% for negative value .For positive value I want border radius at top of bar.

Comment: I am afraid that I don't understand your requirement. Would you like to add an radius for the negative columns?

Comment: I have updated the question, please check once

Answer (score 4):

I prepared a custom code that adds the wanted border radius for positive value - on the top, for negative - on the bottom of the column.

```
$(function() {
  'use strict';
  (function(factory) {
    if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
      module.exports = factory;
    } else {
      factory(Highcharts);
    }
  }(function(Highcharts) {
    (function(H) {
      H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.column.prototype, 'translate', function(proceed) {
        const options = this.options;
        const topMargin = options.topMargin || 0;
        const bottomMargin = options.bottomMargin || 0;

        proceed.call(this);

        H.each(this.points, function(point) {
          console.log(point)
          if (options.customRadius) {
            const w = point.shapeArgs.width;
            const h = point.shapeArgs.height;
            const x = point.shapeArgs.x;
            const y = point.shapeArgs.y;

            let radiusTopLeft,
              radiusTopRight,
              radiusBottomRight,
              radiusBottomLeft;

            if (point.y > 0) {
              radiusTopLeft = H.relativeLength(options.customRadius, w);
              radiusTopRight = H.relativeLength(options.customRadius, w);
              radiusBottomLeft = 0;
              radiusBottomRight = 0;
            } else {
              radiusTopLeft = 0;
              radiusTopRight = 0;
              radiusBottomRight = H.relativeLength(options.customRadius, w);
              radiusBottomLeft = H.relativeLength(options.customRadius, w);
            }

            const maxR = Math.min(w, h) / 2

            radiusTopLeft = radiusTopLeft > maxR ? maxR : radiusTopLeft;
            radiusTopRight = radiusTopRight > maxR ? maxR : radiusTopRight;
            radiusBottomRight = radiusBottomRight > maxR ? maxR : radiusBottomRight;
            radiusBottomLeft = radiusBottomLeft > maxR ? maxR : radiusBottomLeft;

            point.dlBox = point.shapeArgs;

            point.shapeType = 'path';
            point.shapeArgs = {
              d: [
                'M', x + radiusTopLeft, y + topMargin,
                'L', x + w - radiusTopRight, y + topMargin,
                'C', x + w - radiusTopRight / 2, y, x + w, y + radiusTopRight / 2, x + w, y + radiusTopRight,
                'L', x + w, y + h - radiusBottomRight,
                'C', x + w, y + h - radiusBottomRight / 2, x + w - radiusBottomRight / 2, y + h, x + w - radiusBottomRight, y + h + bottomMargin,
                'L', x + radiusBottomLeft, y + h + bottomMargin,
                'C', x + radiusBottomLeft / 2, y + h, x, y + h - radiusBottomLeft / 2, x, y + h - radiusBottomLeft,
                'L', x, y + radiusTopLeft,
                'C', x, y + radiusTopLeft / 2, x + radiusTopLeft / 2, y, x + radiusTopLeft, y,
                'Z'
              ]
            };
          }

        });
      });
    }(Highcharts));
  }));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/okn8qhdb/

Comment: Working Fine, Thank You.

Comment: @Sandhya could you accept this answer? might be useful for other users.